# B-Tree K-D-B Tree and R-Tree improve search

Tags: b-tree, r-tree

How can B-Tree K-D-B Tree and R-Tree help improve efficiency and accuracy of the search.

Comment: Accuracy of search? They all find the entry you're looking for (or tell you that it doesn't exist)

Answer (score 0):

They cannot improve *accuracy* over a linear scan (but unless i plemented incorrectly, they will not be worse either, as both are supposed to give *exact* answers)